# Grabbing more than just one row from DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT title, article, filename, caption FROM articles 
INNER JOIN images WHERE articles.image_id = images.image_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

var_dump($row);
```

This only grabs the first row in the db when what I need is for it to grab all rows.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: By the way, fetch_all() returns an error.

Comment: Is explain in the doc of PHP http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fetch_assoc()`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) returns the next row of the result set with each call, so you need to call it in a loop like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

The loop ends when `$row = null` (i.e. there's no more rows in the result set).

Comment: Why is it then it's not pulling the first row?  There are 3 rows.  It's pulling two but not the first one it seems...

http://screencast.com/t/MEhB5mfWcWN

Comment: It already pulled the first row on line 8 of the code in your image so the call in the loop on line 28 pull the subsequent rows.

Comment: Ok, I apologize.  How would I get it to merely prepare the statement and then fetch all rows in the while loop below?

Comment: Just take out any calls to `fetch_assoc` prior to the loop

Comment: Thank you, sir.  Still learning.  Thanks for being patient with me!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Quick start guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php), more specifically the [Executing statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) chapter. Right from that page:

```
$mysqli->real_query("SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");
$res = $mysqli->use_result();

echo "Result set order...\n";
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " id = " . $row['id'] . "\n";
}
```